# Critical value for Simple vs. Simple Normal Test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $X \sim N(\mu,1)$ and $\mu_0$, $\mu_1$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ with $\mu_0<\mu_1$.
We have the following hypothes $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ and $H_1:\mu=\mu_1$.
I found with the LR test that for small and big values of $x-\mu_0$ we should reject $H_0$ for $H_1$. But now I'm asked to make "small " and "big" quantitative. 
The significance level is given to be $\alpha=0.05$,  and we can choose $\mu_0=0$ and $\mu_1=1$. How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

For this *one*-sided alternative you would reject for $\bar X > \mu_0.$
To find the 'critical value' $k$ for $\alpha = 0.05$ so that you reject for $\bar X \ge k$ and
fail to reject otherwise, you need to find $k$ such that $P(\bar X \ge k\,|\, \mu_0).$

For example, if $\mu_0 = 10$ and $n = 16$ then you want the 95th quantile of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 10, \sigma = 1/4).$ According to R statistical
software (where `qnorm` is the normal 'quantile' or 'inverse CDF' function),
the answer is $k = 10.41.$

```
> qnorm(.95, 10, 1/4)
[1] 10.41121
```

If also $\mu_1 = 11,$ then the probability of Type II Error (failing to
reject when $H_1$ is true) can be found as $P(\bar X < k\,|\,\ mu_1) = 0.009.$

```
> pnorm(10.41, 11, 1/4)
[1] 0.009137468
```

The figure below shows the null distribution of $\bar X$ in blue, the
alternative distribution of $\bar X$ in orange, and the critical value $k$
as a vertical dashed line.

[image]

I suppose this question arises in a theoretical setting, and that you
are expected to answer in terms of the standard normal CDF $\Phi.$ I will
leave it to you to generalize from my specific numerical example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found that you should reject for $x-\mu_0$ both for big and small values. And in your answer you state that you have to reject for $\bar{X}>k$ but we only have one observation. Should it not be  for $X-\mu_0>k$ and $X-\mu_0<c$

Comment: You started off by saying $\mu_0 < \mu_1$ and that $\mu_0$ is the null value. For that test, you would reject for large values of $\bar X.$ If you have one observation $X,$ then $\bar X = X.$ // I don't see how you can get a two-sided test out of the problem as your asked it.